# Is there any limit to the number of users connected via Personal Hotspot?

Tags: iphone, tethering

How many users can be connected to an iPhone's personal hotspot? Does the limit differ from device to device? I want to know the limit of maximum users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from an [Apple support article about Personal Hotspot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204023) (emphasis mine):

> When you connect a device to your Personal Hotspot, the status bar turns blue and shows how many devices have joined. **The number of devices that can join your Personal Hotspot at one time depends on your carrier and iPhone model.**

I believe the typical limit is usually between 3 to 5 devices.

Comment: For iPhone 6S on iOS 15.7.7 maximum is 5 devices. Source is personal experience.

Answer (score -3):

You can have up to 21 people join I have had that many people and I have 5s

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.